# Extract specific information from a transaction

Tags: spl-token, transactions, account, send-transaction, api

I need to extract this info from a transaction:

- `from`, `to` wallet addresses
- `asset`: `SOL` or a token (what token?)
- `amount` transfered
- `block_timestamp`

I know how to get info of a transaction - https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "meta": {
      "err": null,
      "fee": 5000,
      "innerInstructions": [],
      "postBalances": [499998932500, 26858640, 1, 1, 1],
      "postTokenBalances": [],
      "preBalances": [499998937500, 26858640, 1, 1, 1],
      "preTokenBalances": [],
      "rewards": [],
      "status": {
        "Ok": null
      }
    },
    "slot": 430,
    "transaction": {
      "message": {
        "accountKeys": [
          "3UVYmECPPMZSCqWKfENfuoTv51fTDTWicX9xmBD2euKe",
          "AjozzgE83A3x1sHNUR64hfH7zaEBWeMaFuAN9kQgujrc",
          "SysvarS1otHashes111111111111111111111111111",
          "SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111",
          "Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
        ],
        "header": {
          "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,
          "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 3,
          "numRequiredSignatures": 1
        },
        "instructions": [
          {
            "accounts": [1, 2, 3, 0],
            "data": "37u9WtQpcm6ULa3WRQHmj49EPs4if7o9f1jSRVZpm2dvihR9C8jY4NqEwXUbLwx15HBSNcP1",
            "programIdIndex": 4
          }
        ],
        "recentBlockhash": "mfcyqEXB3DnHXki6KjjmZck6YjmZLvpAByy2fj4nh6B"
      },
      "signatures": [
        "2nBhEBYYvfaAe16UMNqRHre4YNSskvuYgx3M6E4JP1oDYvZEJHvoPzyUidNgNX5r9sTyN1J9UxtbCXy2rqYcuyuv"
      ]
    }
  },
  "blockTime": null,
  "id": 1
}
```

However, how to extract all the information above?

I see `blockTime` which may be it.

Also, `preBalances` and `postBalances` - are they the ones to calculate the balances by? Why are they arrays? What each digit correspond to?  Are the digits supposed to be subtracted from as in `postBalances[N] - preBalances[N]`?

All in all, how to extract all the information I need?

P.S.
At the moment I'm only interested in `SOL` and `USDT/USDC` assets.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark this as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In `transaction.message` you can find `accountKeys` those are the accounts for the `postBalance` and `preBalance` in order. This means the first `preBalance` and `postBalance` are for the first `account` in `accountKeys`.

You can get the `from` field by calculating `postBalance - preBalance`. If it's negative then the account tokens were deducted which means it's `from`. if it's zero then it's unchanged. If it's positive then it was transferred to (`to` you are looking for).

**example**

doing this in rust, but it's gonna be similar in typescript since they both invoke the Solana JSON RPC API.

```
{
account_keys: [
    ParsedAccount {
        pubkey:  "9FunJaYzY97hcTNN95mAn8iEhXQjw9NpKDmng8NYLAbt",
        writable: true,
        signer: true 
    },
    ParsedAccount {
        pubkey: "CXFCTHyuhcJL3fiFR5eRochz4k9dwzZWfLMU7knzaCp",
        writable: true,
        signer: false
    }],
}
```

One way to know which token is transferred is to compare the accounts to a mint you know beforehand. But make sure the transaction doesn't have multiple mints.

For the `signer`, a transaction can have multiple signers, they can sign a transaction of a token transfer from one token account to another. use `getParsedTransaction` to get the accounts that are signers or not.

Comment: How about the `from` field?

Comment: You can get the `from` field by calculating `postBalance` - `preBalance`. If it's negative then the account tokens were deducted which means it's from. if it's zero then it's unchanged. If it's positive then it was transferred to.

Comment: The `from` means a wallet address or account a TX was sent from

Comment: the `sender`...

Comment: That's the signer, a transaction can have multiple signers, they can sign a transaction of a token transfer from a token account to another.

Comment: Where is that information in a TX? And how to decode it, if it's not in the plain text?

Comment: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransaction it might be better to use `getParsedTransaction`

Comment: **WHERE** is signer(s) stored in a TX?

Comment: The same question for the destination/receiver - where is it stored in a TX? Re-read my question -- `to`, `from`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141662/discussion-between-vicyyn-and-kum).

Comment: why won't you simply add that information into your answer?

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to ask exactly. Reread my updated answer.